# Add noise and miscalibration to amcl odometry

Tags: gazebo, navigation, turtlebot, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add noise and miscalibration the odometry while using `amcl` to make the turtlebot move from point A to point B. I wrote a subscriber to the `odom` topic and a publisher called `new_odom` that changes the values of the original topic. My question is: how can I make `amcl` use my new topic for localization? I am not sure if I need to modify a launch file, remap a parameter, or change something after the turtlebot has started. More general, how can make any `amcl` to one of my topics instead of the default topic.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246655/add-noise-and-miscalibration-to-amcl-odometry/) by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-09-15**:
Hi,   how did you add noise and miscalibration the odometry in your robot? Could you please share the implementation with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is a bit trickier than just remapping `odom` topic to your `new_odom` topic, because amcl uses `tf` instead of `odom`. You will have to:

1. Disable transform from odom to base_link published by turtle bot (by remapping `tf` topic. Something like this would work: http://answers.ros.org/question/229722/how-to-stop-gazebo-publishing-tf/)
2. Create a node to publish transform from odom to base_link using your new odom data (follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)

After you have done all these, you should check if tf tree is correct by following http://wiki.ros.org/tf#view_frames

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2016-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on 2016-10-30**:
Thanks! I will give it a try and let you know if this approach works.

**Comment by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on 2016-11-09**:
Thanks for the insights! I have been reading the links and for step 2, they create the `/odom` message from scratch, whereas I want to modify the incoming `/odom` and republish them. I think this might not be the complete approach for what I want

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-11-09**:
In the link in step 2, you just need to pay attention to the code from line 40 to 55 because that is how you can broadcast tf from known x, y, th values (which you obtain from your new odom msg). So you can put this code into a callback of a subscriber of odom topic, that should do the trick

**Comment by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on 2016-11-12**:
Thanks for the quick response. I'll give it a shot.

**Comment by [Miguel Velez](https://answers.ros.org/users/27953/miguel-velez/) on 2016-11-15**:
This worked! The only difference is that I had to publish transform from odom to base_footprint, not base_link. I am not sure if that makes a difference. However, it worked and we got the behavior we wanted.